# Center child div in parent div

Tags: css, html, center

I've gotten blind on this one.. I came across other similar topic but none of them helped in the ind.

Long story short, I cant the "a,b,c,d" boxes in the center of the parent div - they need to be aligned to the boxed beneath, so the left is in the very left and the right is all the way to the right.

I've posted my code here in this fiddle, so you can see:
http://jsfiddle.net/sdHhp/

- and my code: `.right_content_wrap{ width: 300px; height: 250px; background: #e3e3e3; float: right; margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; }`

  ```
  .featured_items_wrap{ width: 980px; height: 140px; background: blue; text-align: center;}

  <div class="content_wrap">
  <div class="featured_items_wrap">
      <div class="featured_item">a</div>
      <div class="featured_item">b</div>
      <div class="featured_item">c</div>
      <div class="featured_item">d</div>
  </div>
  ```

If you have any question regarding my issue, feel free to write me!

I'm looking forward to a possible solution!

Thanks a lot and have a great evening ahead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `margin: auto` on the child divs. Also, you needed to make sure that the child divs are not as wide as the wrapper. I made them 75% in the demo and it works.

```
div {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sdHhp/4/

EDIT: Note that this is on the wrapper in your JSFiddle, as that is what holds your child divs.

Further EDIT: I realize that I misunderstood you at first. I believe I have gotten your JSFiddle how you wanted it. Check this one out:

http://jsfiddle.net/sdHhp/9/

Comment: Hey Chad, thanks for the link. I tried to use your tip, but it didn't helped on my example for some reason. See my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdHhp/5/

Comment: I just noticed your fiddle and updated my answer for it. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Chad's anwer if you wanted exactly set within the div you can set a margin of 25px; of course it will vary with size, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/r2pLP/1/

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#one {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#two {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 25px;
}

<div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```